# std::tr1::unordered_map insert error

Tags: c++, unordered-map, tr1

I'm unable to use the insert function for a std::tr1::unordered_map, I keep receiving the following error when attempting to build:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/hashtable:855:14: error: cannot initialize return object of type '_Node *' (aka '_Hash_node<std::pair<const unsigned long long, Order>, false> *') with an rvalue of type 'bool'
      return false;
         ^~~~~
```

My condensed code is as follows:

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
#include "handler.h"
#include "endian_tools.h"

using namespace std::tr1;
using namespace std;

unordered_map<uint64_t, Order> book_by_id;

uint64_t ref_num = be64toh(msg);
Order order(ref_num);

book_by_id.insert(make_pair<uint64_t,Order>(ref_num, order));
```

I thought maybe it had to do with the fact that I was using a long long as the key but even after changing that to an int I get the same error. Any thoughts? I haven't been able to find anyone else with this error anywhere online.

Comment: what is the compiler you are using?

Comment: Just FYI, the reason to use the `std::make_pair` function is so that you don't have to explicitly specify the types (let template type deduction do the work for you). Instead you just do `book_by_id.insert(make_pair(ref_num, order));`

Comment: `tr1::unordered_map` ? How old is your compiler?

Comment: Does your `tr1` implementation have a `std::hash<uint64_t>` specialized ? Is been forever since I looked at someone's tr1 impl, but it may be worth your time to peek at yours.

Comment: I'm using the Mac OSX GCC compiler on Eclipse. The reason I'm using tr1 is because if I just do `#include <unordered_map>` I get an `invalid template arguments` error when I declare the unordered_map. I changed it to tr1 and that fixed the issue. Should I not use tr1 and try to find another way around the invalid template issue?

Comment: It is GCC 4.2.1 I think

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue was with my gcc version and its lack of support for C++11 (Mac OSX uses an old gcc version by default which is how I ended up in this situation). I upgraded my gcc to 4.8 with macports, set it to default, and created a new project with the CrossGCC compiler per these instructions: [use c++11 on mac os x mountain lion with eclipse (Juno or Kepler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163062/use-c11-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-with-eclipse-juno-or-kepler). I removed the tr1 and am now only using `#include <unordered_map>`. Now I have no issue using the insert method.

Thanks all for the suggestions.